fix crashes due to ram overflow
I am using ubuntu operating system. After a period of experience, ubuntu's ram management is really not good. The device often overflows with RAM and cannot be controlled other than turning off the power button. The application is very limited.

What are your configuration ? How much RAM do you have ? And how much swap ? What kind of load (app's) are you running ? Are there anything interesting in the logs around the time of crash ? Oh, and what version of Ubuntu are you using ?

-1: Vague, unanswerable complaints are off-topic here. If you are asking how to fix a specific, reproducible memory overflow, then please edit your question to clearly do so.

1- Increase your swap with help from: Increase swap in 20.04
2- Always have an eye on your ram using desktop applets that let you monitor system resources (like Resource Monitor extension on Gnome or xfce4-systemload-plugin on XFCE, or top/htop commands on terminal)
3- Kill RAM consuming tasks from system monitor apps (gnome-system-monitor if you're on Gnome or xfce4-taskmanager on XFCE)
4- Don't install apps from non-trusted sources as they may have memory leak (btw more important than that is giving away the system's security)
I hope that helps
